# I am executing query using WildcardQuery of Lucene,but it doesn't work

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I am executing query using WildcardQuery of Lucene.but I don't know why the result cannot be found.
Below are the details.

Here is the code for create WildcardQuery,and The record of Field Name :'Full Name' Value:'ABC123DD456CC' is existed Index Document.

```
BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
for (IndexQueryField field : quickSearchFields)
{
    Query query = new WildcardQuery(new Term(queryField.getFieldName(),"ABC*DD*CC"));
    booleanQuery.add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
}
```

The part of code: Executing query:

```
Session hibernateSession               = (Session) em.getDelegate();
FullTextSession session                = SwitchSession.getFullTextSession(hibernateSession, specifyIndexName);

// Set Hibernate flushMode
session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);
// Ignore Hibernate Cache
session.setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE);

            FullTextQuery query = session.createFullTextQuery(booleanQuery,XXX.class);
List list = query.setFirstResult(1).setMaxResults(100).list();
```

The list is empty, i am sure the 'ABC123DD456CC' is existed in Lucene Document.
I just want to do it with WildcardQuery. Any help will be thankful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that last line should be:

```
List list = query.setFirstResult(0).setMaxResults(100).list();
```

Since results are numbered from 0.  If there is only 1 document matching that search, which seems likely enough, that probably explains why you're getting nothing (having skipped the first and only result, at index 0).

Comment: Hi FemtoRgon, Thank you very much!I think it isn't the key point. I have changed the 1 to 0, but it still doesn't work

Comment: All right, well apart from that, I don't see anything wrong with your query.  If it still isn't working, I'd ensure that quickSearchFields contains an item with the FieldName for what you are intending to search, and that in the definition of the class you are attempting to search that field is set to be indexed, rather than just stored.  You could test by just creating a simple Wildcard query for the field your looking for, and see if you get results, that might help you locate the problem more easily, and whether the problem is the query or the way data is saved in the index.

Comment: [Luke](http://www.getopt.org/luke/) is also a good tool to see exactly what is in the index, and whether it's stored and/or indexed, to ensure that isn't the problem.

Comment: FemtoRgon, I written a custom Analyzer,The value of index will be analyzed  when indexing into Document, for example 'I love you' ,it will be analyzed as 'Ilo lov ove vey eyo you', is that means the 'Ilo lov ove vey eyo you' will be indexed for each?  But it's no any analyzer when searching with WildcardQuery. if your inputed value is out of 'Ilo lov ove vey eyo you' , then cannot found anything? is that right?

Comment: Yes, generally you will want to apply the same analyzer to your query.  The way the value is tokenized, no term can possibly match the provided query string (and a Wildcard query will be attempting to match a single term), as none of the tokens indexed are long enough to match.  Using the same analyzer will get you somewhere, but the wildcards still won't get you great results, since terms like 'BC*' will get you a result, 'C*D' will not (no 3 char long substring matches in the example you provided).  I'd say there seems to be a bit of a mismatch between how you index, and how you search.